# What will happen to my GA3 data after 1st July 2023?

Tags: google-analytics

Ive got 10 years of data saved in Google Analytics 3.

On 1st July 2023, GA3 is being discontinued and GA4 is its replacement, buts its not 1:1, none of the data transfers from 3 -> 4

Ive setup GA4 for data going forward.

What will happen to my existing data in GA3 ?

Can i just leave it in there and although it wont be collected / updated further, will i still be able to have it saved and be able to refer to it ?

Or will it all be deleted at 1st July 2023.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Google officially announced in Dec 2023 that all UA data would be deleted on the 1st July 2024, and notifications have been pushed via GA4 to alert users about this. The update was made to the existing support article already linked in this answer.

> After July 1, 2023, you'll be able to access your previously processed data in your Universal Analytics property for at least six months. We know your data is important to you, and we strongly encourage you to export your historical reports during this time.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528

Google have said that you'll have at least six months to review it, and you can export reports to other formats (Google Sheets/Excel/etc) during that time as normal. Do be aware that reports built in Looker Studio utilise live data, so any reliant on UA data will become inoperative after the cut-off date.

Exactly when UA data will become unavailable, I've heard differing reports of 1st January 2024 to 1st July 2024.

I know is that my agency are currently working through our clients' data and making relevant backups. We're not going to be able to get **all** of the data, but we're getting what's relevant to our clients (mostly conversions or other KPI by channel and month).

Comment: Is there any way to backup the data to something that is more visual (eg explorable like GA3) rather than just a spreadsheet backup ?

Comment: @sam - What we're doing for some of our clients is backing UA up to a Google Sheet, then creating a pseudo-Analytics interface in Looker Studio from that. We're still trying to figure out a suitable way of doing that with the behaviour flow graphs.

Comment: Hi Geoff, is this answer up to date? I have been asked by a friend to help make their historical GA3 data usable in GA4, and I'm wondering if that is not possible. From what you wrote above it sounds like that's the case.

Comment: @samthebrand - Google did start showing notifications in GA4 that UA data would be permanently deleted from 1st July 2024.